# Cannot Use json Method in Laravel 5.0

Tags: json, unit-testing, laravel-5

In one of the tutorial of PHPUnit testing that I am learning, the tutor uses

```
    $this->json('POST', "/images/{$image->id}/purchase", [
        'email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
    ]);
```

When I tried to use the same code to implement in my testing, I get exception error like

> BadMethodCallException: The 'json' method does not exist.
>
> C:\wamp64\www\RealTesting\vendor\laracasts\integrated\src\Extensions\IntegrationTrait.php:715

I searched in the Laravel 5.0 documentation, I cannot find the json function.
Where did I go wrong? Is there any way to access json function?

**EDIT**

In Laravel 5.2 documentation, there is a [json function description on how to use](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#testing-json-apis)

But I cannot find for Laravel 5.0 about json function

Comment: Please can you add your code/class here so that we can help you in the right context. Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

If anyone is having trouble with json post in Laravel phpunit, there is an alternative method:

```
$response = $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, $content);
```